# "undefined" after using eval

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting this JSON object from backend services.

```
[{"date":"2014-02-06","fontSize":14,"bgColor":"#000000","fontType":"Arial","userId":1012}]
```

I want to retrieve the elements inside json object and able to use it in my code. but I am getting `undefined` after using eval function 
eg:  `var date_time = data.date_time;`
here i am getting `undefined` for `data.date_time`
 
I have tried the following stuffs. but yet i m getting `undefined`. Please help by giving solution :)
 i have attached the code below. i am a beginner to javascript/json. sry if the question is damn idiot ;)
code :

```
 var getUsersettings= "userId="+userId+"&sessionId="+sessionId; 
                     $.ajax({
                         type:"POST",
                         url: fetchUserSettings,
                         async: false,
                         cache: false,
                         dataType: "json",
                         data: getUsersettings,             
                         error : function(data) {
                             console.log("settings lost while fetching !!!!!");
                         },
                         success : function(data) {
                             console.log("settings fetched !!!!!");
                             if(data != undefined && data.length > 0){
                             console.log(data);
                        //   var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                             var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
                             console.log(obj);
                        //   obj = jQuery.parseJSON(obj);
                        /*   var data =eval('(' +data + ')');
                             console.log(data);
                            */  
                             data = eval('('+obj+')');
                             console.log("obj : "+data);
                             var date_time = data.date_time;
                             var font_size = data.fontSize;
                             var bg_Color = data.bgColor;
                             var font_type = data.fontType;
                             data.userId;
                            // console.log("---"+date_time+"-------"+font_size+"------"+bg_Color+"----"+font_type+"------"+data.userId);
                             }
                             else{
                                 console.log("no data abt fetching");
                             }

                         },
                         complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                             console.log("Status Code: " + xhr.status);
                         }
                     });
```

Comment: Why in the world are you evaluating an object? The code is wrong on many levels.

Comment: You dont have `date_time` in your JSON.

Comment: It's an array containing an object, too, not just an object.

Comment: So you receive `data` object, then you stringify it, and then unpack with eval? Well..

Comment: Go take a look at [json.org](http://json.org) and find out what `[` and `]` denote. Also basic reading skills, `date != date_time`.

Comment: dafug did i just read?! you have an already parsed json as plainobject and you convert it back into a jsonstring to evaluate it to get again a plainobject. holy.... why?! remove the half of your code and it will work

Answer (score 0):

So

i am a little bit confused on what you did in your code.

but jQuery ajax is returning an already parsed json as plainobject.

i think what you missed is, that the first level of your plainobject (json) is an array.
so first of all you have to access the first array item with

```
data[0]
```

after that, the rest is realy easy.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Valtos/4x44n/

Comment: I am a tyro programmer with 15 days of experience.. tried whatever i have googled and got confused.. i missed that json object has sent to front end as an array.. got it now.. .. now able to get the values.. thanks a lot :)